# Firebase authenticate using email/password option doesn't show on assistant

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

can't see the username/password authentication option in android studio's firebase assistant
[Expected Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NelmV.png)

but rather I see this [other authentication options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY7ve.png)

How can I fix this as I need to use email/pass authentication option.
Thank you.

Comment: Where is this? In Firebase Console or What ...

Comment: no in android studio project itself

Comment: Great! .. Can you go to the Web Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) I see it better :)

Comment: You can enable Email/Pass in the Console

Comment: thank you. can you provide steps please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try this in the Firebase Console which I prefer :

To Enable Email/Password in Firebase Console Follow this Steps :

1. Go to The Console ([Link to the Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/))
2. Choose Your Project that You will work with if you did not create project yet Create
   New One
3. Click On Authentication Tab in The Console

[image: Click On Authentication Tab in The Console]

4. Click on Sign-In Method Tab

[image: Click on Sign-In Method Tab]

5. Click on Email/Password Provider Then Click Enable then Click Save

[image: Click on Email/Password Provider Then Click Enable then Click Save]

That is All .. Wish I helped You

Comment: Thank you but this is still on the console side. when I go back to android studio to connect  my app to firebase project, it doesn't display that option on the firebase assistant. How to do so?

Comment: is the authenticate using custom authentication system same as username/password authentication? if so, how to use it?

Comment: @SummerScout The option won't show you would need to do Manual Steps to connect which you can download Google-services.json and connect it to you project.

Comment: @SummerScout Custom Authentication system is **Different** than Email / Password system.